# chained svg filters with feMorphology causes white image in firefox when radius is zero

Tags: firefox, svg, svg-filters

I have the following svg with chained filters (no-op parameters). This shows an image in chrome, but not in firefox.

https://jsfiddle.net/8hpu033j/

```html
<filter  id="filter0" class="image-filter">

                    <feGaussianBlur color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"  stdDeviation="0" result="out1" ></feGaussianBlur>
                    <feColorMatrix color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" type="saturate"  result="out2"  in="out1" values="1"></feColorMatrix>
                    <feColorMatrix color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" type="hueRotate"  result="out3" in="out2" values="0"></feColorMatrix>
                    <feMorphology color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" operator="dilate" result="out4" in="out3" radius="0"></feMorphology>

                  </filter>
```

If I add 0.001 (windows) or 0.0001 (mac) to the feMorphology radius-attribute, the image also shows also in firefox.

https://jsfiddle.net/zbeyhvq7/

```html
<filter  id="filter0" class="image-filter">

                    <feGaussianBlur color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"  stdDeviation="0" result="out1" ></feGaussianBlur>
                    <feColorMatrix color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" type="saturate"  result="out2"  in="out1" values="1"></feColorMatrix>
                    <feColorMatrix color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" type="hueRotate"  result="out3" in="out2" values="0"></feColorMatrix>
                    <feMorphology color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" operator="dilate" result="out4" in="out3" radius="0.001"></feMorphology>

                  </filter>
```

Seems that in firefox the value radius of feMorphologyFilter cannot be 0. If I remove the last filter, everthing is fine.

Am I doing sth. wrong here or is this a firefox bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [SVG specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-SVG11-20030114/filters.html#feMorphology)

> radius = "<number-optional-number>"

...

> A value of zero disables the effect of the given filter primitive (i.e., the result is a transparent black image).

So Firefox is doing it right per the specification, no? Feel free to report a Chrome bug.

Comment: I found that too, but I think that sentence is a bit misleading. Seems webkit people have read the first part of the sentence, and mozilla guys the example in brackets..
Strangely all other filters just don't do anything if the default values are set.

Comment: @mojomajor We can narrow it down a little from *mozilla guys* to basically [it was me](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=485786#c10)